# Rails - File path to load content from a yaml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text, view, yaml

I'm have a variety of text files with static long form text as content.  Right now I am storing them in a separate "content" file in the config folder.  For instance "../config/content/content1.yml" "../config/content/content2.yml" and so on.

I would like to string these files together in my application.  So in my controller I have variables that attempt to pull the content of each file, for example

```
@content1 = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/app/config/content/content1.yml")
@content2 = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/app/config/content/content2.yml")
```

I then try load that variable into my view with

```
<%= @content1 %>
<%= @content2 %>
```

This and everything else I've tried doesn't seem to work though.  I'd really just like to get the text to display in my view.  Any help to point me in the right direction would be much appreciated.  I'm very noobish with rails still.

Comment: I think that you have design problem, not the code problem. What is your main goal? I'm pretty sure that you do it very wrong way.

Comment: I have about 50 separate paragraphs in individual text files.  They are in individual text files because they are edited by different people.  I want to be able to drop the folder containing all the paragraphs into my app and have the app pull them all together.

Comment: Have you thing about using, i.e. Markdown and partials?

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier I'm looking into that right now and that seems like a good solution.  I think the thing I still don't understand is how to reference the file path for markdown.  So how I actually call that content of the markdown file and get it to display in a view.  Like I said, I'm just learning this stuff.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want to store this data in DB, but lets describe what you need using only views.

---

According to comments that what you need are partials.

Example:

Lets have file `app/views/content/editor1/paragraph1.html`:

```
 Example paragraph
```

Then in your view you can render this using:

```
<%= render partial: 'content/editor1/paragraph1' %>
```

Comment: I am getting a "missing template" error when I try this, do I need some specific code in my controller to make this work?